# Oracle SQL - Week Start Sunday and Week End Saturday

Tags: sql, oracle, date, dayofweek

I have the below query to show the week start and week end from a date column. But it is not showing the correct data.

```
trunc(account_date,'iw')-1 week_start,
trunc(account_date,'iw')+7 -1/86400 week_end
```

Week Start should be a Sunday and Week End a Saturday.

From the results (attached) Week End for 01/02/2021, 06/02/2021 should be 06/02/2021.

Week Start for 07/02/21 should be 07/02/2021 and Week End should be 13/02/2021

Any help is appreciated

TIA

Yasir

[image]

Comment: Please read the suggestions about how to ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/. The common SO rules apply too.

Comment: Doesn't "iw" mean "[ISO week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)", which always begins on Monday?

Answer (score 4):

Oracle takes Monday as week start and you need it to be Sunday. This is why I added +1 to the account_date.

Next all you have to do is add 6 days to the week starting day. But

trunc(account_date,'iw')-1 + 6 = trunc(account_date,'iw')+5

```
select account_date,  
       trunc(account_date + 1,'iw')-1 week_start,
       trunc(account_date + 1,'iw')+5 week_end
  from your_table;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I have used the code you have issued but i am getting an incorrect date. For Acc Date 07/02/2021, week start is 31/01/2021 and Week End is 06/02/2021. This should show as Week Start 07/02/2021 and Week End 13/02/2021

Comment: @Yasir I have updated the answer by adding +1 to the account_date